Localhost Hardhat price fetching
I’m trying to get the price during a hardhat test and I don't think it’s fetching the right address.
What I want to do is to test that it’s actually getting the values.
How can I do this? Is it even possible?
Here’s the code of my test file:
const { expect } = require("chai")
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

const MockChainlinkPriceFeed = artifacts.require("MockChainlinkPriceFeed");

const tokens = (n) => {
    return ethers.utils.parseUnits(n.toString(), "ether")
 }

describe("LotteryContract", () => {
    let accounts, user;
    let transaction, result;
    let amount = tokens(10);
    //let lotteryContract;
    beforeEach(async ()=> {
        // We fetch the token from the BC
        const LotteryContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("LotteryContractChainLink");
        const priceFeedAddress = "0x5f4ec3df9cbd43714fe2740f5e3616155c5b8419";
        lotteryContract = await LotteryContract.deploy(MockChainlinkPriceFeed.address);
        await lotteryContract.deployed();
        accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
        user = accounts[0]
        user2 = accounts[1]
        user3 = accounts[2]
        //makes a deposit


It seems to me that the line
lotteryContract = await LotteryContract.deploy(MockChainlinkPriceFeed.address);

doesn't make sense because you don't have any contract instance.
If you are trying to get a contract already deployed at a specified address, and this is a fork, you should create a ContractFactory for your MockChainlinkPriceFeed contract, and call the attach method with the given address as argument (ethers.js documentation) to get the contract instance at that address.
I hope I understood your question well...

I did but i dont understand the method as i just need a value to try to finalise my contract.

1 . You need to instantiate the ContractFactory (const MockFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MockChainlinkPriceFeed");)
2. Then you call attach to get an instance of the contract if it is already deployed (with your priceFeedAddress : const MockPriceFeedInstance = MockFactory.attach(priceFeedAddress);).

You pass MockPriceFeedInstance.address as argument in place of MockChainlinkPriceFeed.address to the line in the original answer.

If it is not already deployed, you need to deploy it instead of calling attach...
